# flex+bison, sections with different syntaxes

Tags: bison, flex-lexer

I am working on a parser in flex & bison which is supposed to parse source codes which have different sections that have different syntaxes.

think of php, which just "stupidly" dumps everything until it finds a 
`<?php`, then it goes into a syntactic part that actually parses stuff and when it finds a `?>` it goes back to dumping.

So while I am in a "dumping" section, the scanner should only provide raw strings. meaningful tokens (WHILE, OPENPARENTHESIS, IDENTIFIER, etc.) should only be provided in the syntactic sections and a \ starts a syntactic section.

I have found that you can give the flex rules different ["start conditions"](http://westes.github.io/flex/manual/Start-Conditions.html), 
so I can basically switch between different scanners like

```
%x semantic
%x dump
%%
<dump>"\\"        { BEGIN(semantic); }
<dump>.           { (*yylval).stringvalue = yytext; return yy::parser::token::CHAR;}
<semantic>"while" {return yy::parser::token::WHILE;}
```

which is really what I need here.

My problem is that the end of a syntactic section cannot be described with a regular expression, so this decision cannot be done within the scanner, it has to be made by the parser. I basically want it to go back to dump mode "in between rules". So I want to do something like

```
CODEELEMENT: FOR OPEN STATEMENT SEMICOLON BOOL SEMICOLON STATEMENT CLOSE <<GO TO DUMP MODE>> ELEMENT
```

you can probably tell, this is supposed to become a rule for something like a for-loop in C, but the "body" (the ELEMENT) is supposed to be read as dump again (this would deliver only a single character, unless you grouped multiple characters together with { and } again)

I know that bison can execute code "in between rules", I tried to declare a global variable (ugh) "dumpmode", put a {dumpmode = true;} into the rule like this

```
CODEELEMENT: FOR OPEN STATEMENT SEMICOLON BOOL SEMICOLON STATEMENT CLOSE {dumpmode = true;} ELEMENT
```

and put

```
if(dumpmode)
{
    BEGIN(dump);
    dumpmode = false;
}
```

in front of the flex rules (this is similar to the example on the page I have linked above)

But this does not work and it actually makes sense - AFAIK bison already needs the final ELEMENT token to decide to use that rule (so the code won't be executed before the token comes), but this token would only be produced by the dump mode, which is not active at that point in the process.

Do you know a way to do this? Switching the start-condition of the flexer from the bison code in between the rules? maybe I'd need to break the bison rules apart like

```
CODEELEMENT: FOR1 FOR2
    ;
FOR1: FOR OPEN STATEMENT SEMICOLON BOOL SEMICOLON STATEMENT CLOSE {dumpmode = true;}
    ;
FOR2: ELEMENT
    ;
```

but I don't think this approach would work with if-then-else constructs...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try the function [`void yy_pop_state ()`](http://westes.github.io/flex/manual/Start-Conditions.html), calling it from the Bison part ?